# Contextual help in Xcode not showing

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation

I'm trying to use 'Option-click' to see inline documentation in xcode. Here's what I get when I Option-click 'hasPrefix()':

[image]

Here's what I'm supposed to get:

[image]

How to fix? I've tried installing the command line tools from dev.apple site.

xcode 10.0 / swift 4

Comment: Sometimes restarting `Xcode` will fix such issues.

Comment: A restart didn't fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the above code was from a Playground, which doesn't have the same docs feature as normal Xcode.

Still want to see full doco in a Playground? Press Apple-Shift-0 and you'll get the reference. Or visit https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html